# Enable Win+X menu afer moving UserProfiles

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, sysprep

After I've moved the C:\Users directory with this response file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
            <DoNotCleanTaskBar>true</DoNotCleanTaskBar>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FolderLocations>
                <ProfilesDirectory>D:\Users\</ProfilesDirectory>
            </FolderLocations>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:e:/sources/install.wim#Windows 10 Pro" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

And this command

```
%windir%\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /reboot /unattend:d:\relocate.xml
```

I was able to create a new account in OOBE and all existing accounts were successfully move to the D: device (a raid0). After this sysprep the folder C:\Users was no longer used and all profiles were moved to D:\Users.

However in the new situation the Win+X nor right click on the Windows start button do anything. Is this related and how do I reactivate the Win+X or Start button context menu?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot practically move all of C:\Users\jusername\AppData.

Some of the data in there cannot be readily moved, that is moving may break some things.

Did you take this into account?  That is maybe why some things do not work.

You may have a User Profile error because of the move.

You would not normally set up a user profile before sysprep, and I think that is where the error lies.

Comment: Ok. Well I just did. The Users folder no longer exists on C: but sits on D: now after the sysprep.

Comment: Some things in appdata may break when you move them II clarified my answer in this respect).

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is absolutely no reason the entire user profile, including AppData, must exist in the system drive. In fact I know this isn’t the case since, my virtualized environment, uses an externally static mounted virtual HDD in order to instantaneously provide the same user profile to virtual machines after they have been rebuilt after their VMWare Horizon session has been released

Comment: The AppData folder is C:UsersYourUserNameAppData. Then you can see 3 folders in the AppData folder, Local, LocalLow, and Roaming. Local: It holds data that cannot be moved, e.g. the temporary files of Excel, web browsers. LocalLow: It contains data that cannot be moved, e.g. web browser data in a safe mode.   ...   One ref:  www.apeaksoft.com/recovery/find-deleted-missing-appdata.html   ....  I don't think my answer is wrong.

Comment: I also that one would not normally add a user profile before sysprep to help clarify